# ul, li.. have the text right under the textstart instead of the li image on the second row

Tags: html, css

I got a `<ul>` with `list-style-image`

now my problem is that i cant figure how to have the text flow right under the start of the text on the second row instead of it going under the image (or any type of style for that matter).

```
 - text
 - text
 - text how it 
 is now


 - text
 - text
 - text how i 
   want it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this:

```
ul{
 list-style-position:outside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [list-style-position](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-position) property  ans set it to outside:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/KVkcV/)**